# Compilation error when base and derived classes defined in separate namespaces

Tags: c++

I have defined base class and derived class in separate namepsaces(This is a requirement as several classes can be derived from a single base class and based on behaviour of derived classes they are to be place din separate namespaces.)

```
Base.h

namespace global
{

    {
    class Base
    {
    public:
        Base();
        virtual ~Base();    

        virtual int someFunc(int arg1);
    }
}

Derived.h

namespace global
{
    namespace derived
    {

    class Derived: public Base()
    {
    public:
        Derived();
        ~Derived();
    }   
    }
}

Derived.cpp

namespace global
{
    namespace derived
    {
    Derived::Derived() {}
    Derived::~Derived() {}

    int Derived::someFunc(int arg1)
    {
    //some code here
    }
    }
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the error:

**no 'int global::derived::Derived::someFunc(int arg1)' member function declared in class global::derived::Derived.**

So, do I need to declare someFunc in Derived again?

like:

```
namespace global
{
    namespace derived
    {

    class Derived: public Base()
    {
    public:
        Derived();
        ~Derived();
        int someFunc(arg1 int);
    }   
    }
}
```

Now, if there is some Function in a totally separate namespace, that accepts base class reference, how can I pass it derived class reference?

```
tryFunc(Base &b);

Derived d;
tryFunc(d);
```

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically figured out everything already, you got to declare `someFunc` in the class body of the derived class.

Also the way of passing to `tryFunc(Base &b)`is correct